# TYPO3 tx_form conditional skip steps

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-8.x

I using TYPO3 8 LTS and i want to extend the form.

Right now I am trying to add a condition in my form that skips all other steps and runs my finishers. In the documentation it is written that you have to use the afterInitializeCurrentPage function:

```
/**
 * @param FormRuntime $formRuntime
 * @param CompositeRenderableInterface $currentPage
 * @param null|CompositeRenderableInterface $lastPage
 * @param mixed $requestArguments submitted value of the element *before post processing*
 * @return CompositeRenderableInterface
 */
public function afterInitializeCurrentPage(
    FormRuntime $formRuntime,
    CompositeRenderableInterface $currentPage,
    CompositeRenderableInterface $lastPage = null,
    array $requestArguments = []
): CompositeRenderableInterface {

    if ($requestArguments['personalized'] === '0') {
        // code here ...
    }

    return $currentPage;
}
```

My problem is i do not know how i execute the finishers out of this function..

i hope someone can give me a hint or something else..

[EDIT]

next problem is if i use the afterInitializeCurrentPage method i get an exception for other forms in my site:

```
Argument 2 passed to VENDOR\YourNamespace\YourClass::afterInitializeCurrentPage() must implement interface TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\CompositeRenderableInterface, null given, called in [..]/typo3/sysext/form/Classes/Domain/Runtime/FormRuntime.php on line 254
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the finisher Class Like below.

You need to add below line in `ext_localconf.php` file. like this

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ext/form']['afterInitializeCurrentPage'][]
    = \VENDOR\YourNamespace\Hooks\YourClass::class;
```

After added this function like below on path Classes/Hooks/YourClass.php.

```
<?php
namespace \VENDOR\YourNamespace\Hooks;

class YourClass
{
    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Runtime\FormRuntime $formRuntime
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\CompositeRenderableInterface $currentPage
     * @param null|\TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\CompositeRenderableInterface $lastPage
     * @param mixed $elementValue submitted value of the element *before post processing*
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\CompositeRenderableInterface
     */
    public function afterInitializeCurrentPage(\TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Runtime\FormRuntime $formRuntime, \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\CompositeRenderableInterface $currentPage, \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\Renderable\CompositeRenderableInterface $lastPage = null, array $requestArguments = []): CompositeRenderableInterface
    {
        return $currentPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, i have a Class with this method and i added it in my ext_localconf, but my problem is how can i force the method to execute the finishers?